# Spring batch: read xml as DOM Document

Tags: xml, dom, spring-batch

I want to read a large xml file which includes n number of elements 'elem1'. n can be up to 10.000 or more. I want to read each eleme1 as a DOM document, process it and read next elem1 etc.
All articles I found so far suggest using StaxEventItemReader. But I don't want to map the peeked 'elem1' to an object but a DOM document. The reason is, that the business logic which I want to integrate in proccessor allready exists. The logic handles with a DOM Document(reading Nodes etc..). However StaxEventItemReader expects a class type to map the read data to. Is there any way to read data just as a dom document? I was thinking of a multiline records reader and defining open/close tags as tockenizers. But I don't know if this is possible and whether it is the right way?

```
 <root>
    <elem1>
        <a>...</a>
        <b>...</b>
    </elem1> 

    <elem1>
        <a>...</a>
        <b>...</b>
        <c>...</c>
    </elem1> 

</root>
```

Comment: If you have a string `<elem1> .. </elem1>`, would you be able to convert it in a DOM document? Do you have the code for that?

Comment: Yes I am able. In my Unit Test I do write such an XML as string and feed it into my process where it get parsed into a DOM Doc.

Comment: ok thanks. I added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are able to parse a string element into a DOM object, you can proceed as follows:

- Use a `StaxEventItemReader<String>` to read string elements
- Use a processor to transform string items into DOM items
- Add another processor (in a composite processor) to process DOM items as needed (call the business logic that you already have and which expects DOM items)